# How to include empty datetime in python dict

Tags: python, dictionary

The dictionary I currently have is

```
data = {'Jun 2006': 300.0, 'Nov 2006': 200.0}
```

The output I'm looking for is

```
data = {'Jun 2006': 300.0, 'Jul 2006': 0, 'Aug 2006': 0, 'Sep 2006': 0, 'Oct 2006': 0, 'Nov 2006': 200.0}
```

My current code

```
data = {'Jun 2006': 300.0, 'Nov 2006': 200.0}

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

month_range = pd.date_range(start=list(data.keys())[0], end=list(data.keys())[-1], freq='MS').strftime('%b %Y').tolist()

final_data = {}
for month in month_range:
    if(month in data):
        final_data[month] = data[month]
    else:
        final_data[month] = 0

print(final_data)
```

Comment: What does this code do wrong?

Comment: Is this code throwing any error?

Comment: Just tested it and it outputs `{'Jun 2006': 300.0, 'Jul 2006': 0, 'Aug 2006': 0, 'Sep 2006': 0, 'Oct 2006': 0, 'Nov 2006': 200.0}` as required

Comment: I wanted a more sophisticated way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a pandas Series and fill it with zeros -

```
pd.Series(data, index=month_range).fillna(0).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a non-pandas solution,

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import datetime

data = {'Jun 2006': 300.0, 'Nov 2006': 200.0}
result = {}

start = datetime.datetime.strptime(list(data.keys())[0], '%b %Y')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime(list(data.keys())[-1], '%b %Y')

while start <= end:

    start_month = datetime.datetime.strftime(start, '%b %Y')
    result[start_month] = data.get(start_month, 0)
    start += relativedelta(months=1)    
    
print(result)

{'Jun 2006': 300.0,
 'Jul 2006': 0,
 'Aug 2006': 0,
 'Sep 2006': 0,
 'Oct 2006': 0,
 'Nov 2006': 200.0}
```